# How to populate a cell based off drop down menu in vba form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get cells to populate depending on what is selected off the drop down list on my form.  If (2) selections on the drop down are picked, more options on the form open up and I am trying to get cells to populate based on the extra selections made

Current

```
page.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
page.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.weektxtbx.Value
page.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
page.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Me.daystxtbx.Value
page.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = Me.commenttextbx.Value
If Me.Expedite_yes.Value = True Then page.Range("E" & n + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
If Me.ExpediteNo.Value = True Then page.Range("E" & n + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed

swp = Me.ComboBox1.Value
If swp = "EPT" Then
    page.Range("G").Value = Me.A1text.Value
End If
```

The `page.range("A" & n + 1).value = me.combobox1.value` and similar lines of code correctly populate the cells on the worksheet but  the second half the code does not work.

```
if swp= "EPT" then 
       page.Range("G").value = Me.A1Text.value
End if
```

gives an object error and I am stumped. The macro will not even run through to that point.

Comment: First question: do you have a range named `"G"` or did you mean to include `& n + 1`?

Comment: Yes! I have tried both and get the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `n` when you get the error and what is the specific error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Range("G").value** is not eferencing an actual range. If you did **Range("G:G").value**, the entire column contents would be affected. Do you mean **Range("G" & n + 1).value**?

Comment: Yes! sorry, it should be Range("G" & n +1).value but I am still getting the same error